# Solving error "Expression of generated column 'registrationno' contains a disallowed function"

Tags: mysql

Can someone tell me the right way of doing an generated column in mysql.
im supposed to generate a registration_no in format:

```
SVSRYYYYinvoice_no
yyyy-> year
```

I have been using MYSQL workbench to create my db but i'm getting this error

```
ERROR 3102: Expression of generated column 'registrationno' contains a disallowed function.
SQL Statement:>CREATE TABLE `invoicegeneration`.`registration` (
`invoice_no` SMALLINT(4) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`amount` INT(11) NULL,
`name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`invoice_date` DATETIME NULL,
`amt_in_words` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`mop` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`registrationcol` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`dated` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`drawn_on` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`course` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`towards` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`duration` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`registrationno` VARCHAR(45) GENERATED ALWAYS AS
(CONCAT('SVSR',YEAR(CURDATE()),invoice_no)) STORED,
PRIMARY KEY (`invoice_no`),
UNIQUE INDEX `invoice_no_UNIQUE` (`invoice_no` ASC))
```

Can someone show me the right way to create the generated column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot create a virtual column based on non-deterministic function, as that would cause problems during replication.
[See the “Limitations section in this blog post for more details](http://mysqlserverteam.com/virtual-columns-and-effective-functional-indexes-in-innodb/).

You already have the `invoice_date` column, so a better solution would be to replace the column definition for registrationno with something like:

```
registrationno VARCHAR(45) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CONCAT('SVSR',YEAR(invoice_date),invoice_no)) STORED
```

As a further optimization you could store the year of the invoice_date as a stand-alone column. This would allow you to place an index on it and then do analysis by year, or partition the table by year if your data grows huge.